# Calculating area of snow cover in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, copernicus

I want to calculate the area for snow cover but it doesn’t work out for me.

[image: error]

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') 
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10)) 
  .filterDate('2020-04-01' ,'2020-04-27') 
  .filterBounds(polygon) ;


print(collection) ;

  //Let's centre the map view over our ROI
Map.centerObject(polygon, 13);
var medianpixels = collection.median(); // This finds the median value of all the pixels which meet the criteria. 

var medianpixelsclipped = medianpixels.clip(polygon).divide(10000);
// Now visualise the mosaic as a natural colour image. 
Map.addLayer(medianpixelsclipped, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 1, gamma: 1.5}, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic',false);

// User specified parameters

// setup Visualization
var viz = {min:-0.50, max:0.75, palette:['red', 'green', 'orange', 'white']};

// Data
// calculate ndsi
var ndsi = medianpixelsclipped.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B11']);
var scale=30;
Map.addLayer(ndsi, {min:0.4, max:1, palette:['EB984E ','FDFEFE  ']}, 'ndsi');
var reducer = ndsi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
geometry: polygon,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1E13
});
// km square
var area = ee.Number(reducer.get('NDSI')).multiply(scale).multiply(scale).divide(1000000);
print('area of ndsi ', area.getInfo() + ' km2');
```

Answer (score 4):

it looks like you dont have a band named 'NDSI'. Try adding this code:

```
var ndsi = medianpixelsclipped.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B11']).rename('NDSI');
```

However, you need to make some changes in your code if you want to get the snow area. 
The Ndsi range is between -1 and 1;  you are adding continuous values ​​in that range so it is perfectly possible to have a negative value as a result. In general, snow is considered to have values greater than 0. So if your goal is to count 'snow' pixels in your region you should make a binary image 'snow' -- 'not snow'. For example change your ndsi line with this:

```
var snow = medianpixelsclipped.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B11']).gt(0). rename('snow');
```

Then you can reduce with ee.Reducer.histogram(). This will give you an object with the number of pixels with value 1 (snow) and the number of non snow pixels (value 0)

```
var reducer = ndsi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(),
geometry: polygon,
scale: 30,
bestEffort: true
});
```

Finally, extract the snow pixels count:

```
var dict = ee.Dictionary(rgHist.get('snow'));
var histogram = dict.get('histogram');
var list = ee.List(histogram);
var snow = list.get(1)
var area = ee.Number(snow).multiply(scale).multiply(scale).divide(1000000)
```

Note that i dont have your data so im not sure how is your reducer output going to be. You may have to make small changes in the last .get(). First inspect if you do have pixels with 1 as value.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: but I want to find out, I count on summer pictures for verification and he considers the area with a minus, you don’t know why?

Comment: @Ayazhan Karabaeva i have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is very important information for me! I'm new to google earth engine and sorry to bother you, but I have one more question. Engine shows me this error:"rgHist" is not defined in this scope. Do I need to put "snow" there?

Comment: My mistake. Put reducer

Comment: thank you very much! everything works and only snow counts !!!

Comment: @AyazhanKarabaeva kindly accept this as answer, if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

For me you would have to rewrite the last line like this:

```js
var area = ee.Number(reducer.get('ndsi')).multiply(scale).multiply(scale).divide(1000000);
print('area of ndsi ', area.getInfo() + ' km2');
```

Comment: but I want to find out, I count on summer pictures for verification and he considers the area with a minus, you don’t know why?